# Use library with static dependencies in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, header, dependencies, static-libraries

Is there a way in CMake to use a library for multiple targets with different static dependencies?
To explain it better, consider this minimal example: I want two executables: The first should print "YES", the second one should print "NO". For this I use the libarary "printsth", which prints "something". The string it prints comes from the header file the "user" (either printyes or printno) supplies. This altogether looks like this:

```
├── apps
│   ├── printno
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │       add_executable(printno main.cpp)
│   │   │       target_link_libraries(printno PRIVATE printsth)
│   │   │
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   │       #include "printsth/printsth.h"
│   │   │       
│   │   │       int main() {
│   │   │         printsth();
│   │   │         return 0;
│   │   │       }
│   │   │
│   │   └── print_usr.h
│   │           #define USR_STRING  "NO"
│   │
│   └── printyes
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │       add_executable(printyes main.cpp)
│   │   │       target_link_libraries(printyes PRIVATE printsth)
│   │   │
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   │       #include "printsth/printsth.h"
│   │   │       
│   │   │       int main() {
│   │   │         printsth();
│   │   │         return 0;
│   │   │       }
│   │   │
│   │   └── print_usr.h
│   │           #define USR_STRING  "YES"
│   │
├── extern
│   └── printsh
│       ├── include
│       │   └── printsh
│       │       └── printsh.h
│       │               void printsth();
│       │
│       ├── src
│       │    ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │    │       add_library(printsth printsth.cpp)
│       │    │       target_include_directories(printsth PUBLIC ../include)
│       │    │
│       │    └── printsh.cpp
│       │            #include "printsth/printsth.h"
│       │            #include "print_usr.h"
│       │            #include <iostream>
│       │            
│       │            void printsth() {
│       │              std::cout << USR_STRING << std::endl;
│       │            }
│       │     
│       └── CMakeLists.txt
│               cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11...3.16)
│               
│               project(printsh
│                   VERSION 0.1
│                   DESCRIPTION "Print something"
│                   LANGUAGES CXX)
│               
│               add_subdirectory(src)
│        
└── CMakeLists.txt
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11...3.16)

        project(printexamples
            VERSION 0.1
            DESCRIPTION "Print examples"
            LANGUAGES CXX)

        add_subdirectory(apps/printyes)
        add_subdirectory(apps/printno)
        add_subdirectory(extern/printsth)
```

When building I obviously get the error

```
fatal error: print_usr.h: No such file or directory
```

So is there any change I can tell CMake to use apps/printno as include directory when building printsh lib for printno and to use apps/printyes as include directory when building for printyes?

I know this example does not make much sense and it is easy to get rid of the header dependencies (e.g. passing the custom string as an argument to printsth()) and everything works just fine. So this is just an example to demonstrate a "real-world" problem, where I can't easily get rid of the dependencies.

Comment: do you mean something like if else in the cmake?

Comment: A library is not "built for..." it's just built once and then linked together with other module(s). CMake doesn't change how libraries work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a great first question! One way to do this, other than completely re-designing to remove the dependency, would be to create a "yes" and a "no" version of your `printsh` library. Then, link the correct "yes" or "no" version of the library to `printyes` and `printno`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see it is actually not a real static library. @squareskittles The problem is, that in "reality" this can be quite a few different versions, and I would like to keep the libraray (printsth) independent of the configuration. Another approach would be to include the library sources directly into executable, but I don't see any way to still be able to control inlcude paths etc just for the library source files.

Answer (score 1):

In CMake sense a **library target** denotes the library which is **compiled once** but can be linked into several targets(executable or other libraries).

Because you cannot compile both macro definitions into the single library, you need to create a **different library target** for every definitions set. That is, in your case you need to create **two libraries**.

For repetitive sequence of commands CMake provides macros and functions and call them several times with different parameters.

You may also create a "parameterized" `CMakeLists.txt`, and "call" it (via `add_subdirectory`) several times:

**extern/printsh/src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Requires 'printsth_target' and 'printish_usr_dir' variables to be set.
# The first variable denotes name of the target created,
# the second variable denotes include directory with 'print_usr.h' header.
if (NOT printsth_target)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "printsth_target variable is required but is not set.")
endif()
if (NOT printish_usr_dir)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "printish_usr_dir variable is required but is not set.")
endif()

# Create a library target with user-provided name
add_library(${printsth_target} printsth.cpp)
target_include_directories(${printsth_target} PUBLIC ../include)
# Add user-provided include directory
target_include_directories(${printsth_target} PRIVATE ${printish_usr_dir})
```

With such script the `printsth` library can be *instantiated* in applications'  `CMakeLists.txt`.

**apps/printno/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(printno main.cpp)
# Instantiate 'printsth' library with needed parameters.
set(printsth_target "printsh_no")
set(printish_usr_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
# Need to specify the second argument - build directory, where the library will be built.
add_subdirectory(../../extern/printsh printsh_no_dir)
# No we can link with a library. Use a name, specified for 'printsth_target' variable.
target_link_libraries(printno PRIVATE printsh_no)
```

Top-level `CMakeLists.txt` should be modified for not instantiate the library.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# <...>

add_subdirectory(apps/printyes)
add_subdirectory(apps/printno)
# Uncommenting the following line causes FATAL_ERROR triggered.
#add_subdirectory(extern/printsth)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! This was exactly what I was looking for. The only part I don't really get is what add_subdirectory() does and why it is necessary (If I build a standard, non parametrized libraray I don't have to use add_subdirectory()).

Comment: In your original code you use `add_subdirectory(extern/printsth)` in the root `CMakeLists.txt` for instantiate (build) the library. In my variant there are two such calls in the `apps/printno/CMakeLists.txt` and `apps/printyes/CMakeLists.txt` (the latter file is not shown because it is similar to the former).